# Why does the first button sends their kind values but the others cant, per container

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE: To future readers**

*The solution has been provided make sure you look at my answer and charlietfl's answers below.*

**Post before solution**

I have this script that I made that sends values to a page call x.php. The way it works is each red container has it's own inputs and button so if you click on any

of those red container button it will send their container input values to page x.php so those values can be echoed.

The problem is that it can send any of the buttons request but it only sends the first red container input values if I would do that to the other containers it just sends the first red container input values to be echoed

but not their own so how can I do it in a way where it will send their red container values.

This is how it will look like if I get it to work the way I want it to work

[.gif-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPGQn.gif)

Here is the code

**index.php**

```
<style>

    .dataContainer{
      background-color: red;
      width: 185px;
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 25px; 
    }

    .dataContainerDesign .a,.b,.send{
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }

 </style>

    <script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

var containerButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.dataContainer .send');

 for (var i = 0; i < containerButtons.length; i++) {
   containerButtons[i].addEventListener('click', perContainer);
 }

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        document.querySelector('.dataContainer').innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
    }
};

function perContainer(){

    var data = new FormData();

  //Var structrue
  var a=  document.querySelector('.a').value;
  var b=  document.querySelector('.b').value;
//

//Data var
data.append('a', a);
data.append('b', b);
//
    xhr.open('POST','x'); 
    xhr.send(data);
}
});
    </script>

    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input class='a' type='text'>
      <input class='b' type='text'>
      <button class='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->

    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input class='a' type='text'>
      <input class='b' type='text'>
      <button class='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->

    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input class='a' type='text'>
      <input class='b' type='text'>
      <button class='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->

    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input class='a' type='text'>
      <input class='b' type='text'>
      <button class='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->
```

**x.php**

```
<p style='display: inline-block;'>
<?php
$a= $_POST['a'];
$b= $_POST['b'];
echo 'Sent Values: ';
echo $a.','.$b;
?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `document.querySelector('.a')` will return the first element with that class found in the document.

You need to look for that class within the specific button's siblings

One way is to isolate the parent of the button and query within that parent. I left out the XHR and FormData just to simplify demo and to log the associated values to console instead

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var containerButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.dataContainer .send');

  for (var i = 0; i < containerButtons.length; i++) {
    containerButtons[i].addEventListener('click', perContainer);
  }
  
});


function perContainer(evt) {
  // from event object get button clicked
  let button = evt.currentTarget,
  // and isolate the parent container
    div = button.parentNode;

  //query only within the parent container
  var a=  div.querySelector('.a').value;
  var b=  div.querySelector('.b').value;  

  console.log([a, b]);
}
```

```html
<div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
  <input class='a' type='text' value="a1">
  <input class='b' type='text' value="b1">
  <button class='send'>Send</button>
</div>
<!--</dataContainer>-->

<div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
  <input class='a' type='text' value="a2">
  <input class='b' type='text' value="b2">
  <button class='send'>Send</button>
</div>
<!--</dataContainer>-->

<div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
  <input class='a' type='text' value="a3">
  <input class='b' type='text' value="b3">
  <button class='send'>Send</button>
</div>
<!--</dataContainer>-->

<div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
  <input class='a' type='text' value="a4">
  <input class='b' type='text' value="b4">
  <button class='send'>Send</button>
</div>
<!--</dataContainer>-->
```

Comment: Thanks charlietfl I tested that in the console and your example looks good but how can I integrate your example based on my code because I tried to integrate your method to my code and it still sends the first container values can your provide an example of my code included with FormData() with your method I have no errors it just sends the first container values if you don't mind.

Comment: One problem is you need a new `XMLHttpRequest` for every request and have the same issue using `querySelector('.dataContainer')`

Comment: Here is what i'm doing https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MGdWKGU0oeyOES8hbHTt5aEDKjNSEWQ0Fnzv53XYnCI/edit

Comment: Create the request inside `perContainer()` and use `div` to target the response data with

Comment: I updated the link so like this? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MGdWKGU0oeyOES8hbHTt5aEDKjNSEWQ0Fnzv53XYnCI/edit

Comment: Close but you want to target the response into specific `div` don't you? Define `button` and `div` first and just do `div.innerHTML` instead of `document.querySelector('.dataContainer').innerHTML`

Comment: Yes like every time I press the button it will look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSX40.gif

Comment: Basically just like that .gif the response will be in that red container that the button was pressed in.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MGdWKGU0oeyOES8hbHTt5aEDKjNSEWQ0Fnzv53XYnCI/edit       Same result still it still does not work I don't mean to sound rude or demanding but i'm under a lot of pressure right now for a client can you update your code example with FormData() and give me a direct example rather than hints it's just my client has been calling me constantly and I will really appreciate that if you can update your code example with form data with ajax. I will study it when I can.

Comment: `div.innerHTML;` doesn't do anything.... need to do `div.innerHTML= xhr.responseText`

Comment: Sorry about earlier charlietfl I was under a lot of pressure earlier because of your help I figured it out thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to charlietfl for teaching me how to solve this because of charlietfl I was able to solve this so i'm ma reward **charlietfl's answer** as the hint solution but I combine charlietfl's

way and my way just in case if any future reader wants to know how this looks completed, how I always intended it to be.

Ok here is the ***completed code that works***.

**index.php**

```
<style>

.dataContainer{
  background-color: red;
  width: 205px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px; 
}

.dataContainerDesign .first_name,.last_name,.send{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

 </style>

    <script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

var dataContainerSendButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.dataContainer .send');

 for (var i = 0; i < dataContainerSendButtons.length; i++) {
   dataContainerSendButtons[i].addEventListener('click', dataContainerProcess);
 }

function dataContainerProcess(execution){

var send = execution.currentTarget;
  var dataContainer = send.parentNode;

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        dataContainer.innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
    }
}

    var data = new FormData();

  //Var structrue
   var first_name=  dataContainer.querySelector('.first_name').value;
   var last_name=  dataContainer.querySelector('.last_name').value;
   var image=  dataContainer.querySelector('.image').files[0];
//

//Data var
data.append('first_name', first_name);
data.append('last_name', last_name);
data.append('image',image);
//
    xhr.open('POST','x'); 
    xhr.send(data);
}

});

    </script>

    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input class='first_name' type='text'>
      <input class='last_name' type='text'>
      <input class='image' type='file'>
      <button class='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->

    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input class='first_name' type='text'>
      <input class='last_name' type='text'>
      <input class='image' type='file'>
      <button class='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->

    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input class='first_name' type='text'>
      <input class='last_name' type='text'>
      <input class='image' type='file'>
      <button class='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->

    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input class='first_name' type='text'>
      <input class='last_name' type='text'>
      <input class='image' type='file'>
      <button class='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->
```

**x.php**

```
<?php

$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];

if($_FILES['image']['name'] != '')
{
 $image_test = explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']);
 $image_ext = end($image_test);
 $image_prefix= 'random';
 $image_file_name = $image_prefix . uniqid() . '.' . $image_ext;
 $image_directory = 'images/';
 $image_location = $image_directory.$image_file_name;  
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $image_location);

 $profile_image= $image_location;
}

?>

<style>

img{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

</style>

<img src='<?php echo $profile_image; ?>'>
<h1><?php echo $first_name; ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $last_name; ?></h1>
```